# Extracting an element from a list with a logical vector containing at most one `TRUE` value in R

Tags: r, list

I want to extract an element from a list based on a logical vector where at most one `TRUE` value indicates the desired element. Sometimes, the logical vector might contain only `FALSE` values.

Consider this example:

```r
my_list <- list(10, "a", 30)
logical_vector <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE) # or logical_vector <- c(F, F, F)
```

The following solutions work but none is straightfoward enough for me

```r
# Solution no. 1 : using `which`:
if (any(logical_vector)) my_list[[which(logical_vector)]] else list()
# [1] 30

# Solution no. 2 : using `dplyr::first`:
dplyr::first(my_list[logical_vector)]) 
# [1] 30
```

The solution must work when `logical_vector <- c(F, F, F)`

Comment: `my_list[logical_vector] |> unlist()` ?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by "work" when the the vector is all FALSE. My above suggestion gives `NULL`, which seems appropriate. If you want a specific output like `list()`, then your `if` statement is probably the best.

Comment: You could also use `my_list[[match(TRUE, logical_vector)]]` for a `NULL` in the all-FALSE case. The difference between this and my first suggestion is what happens if there is more than 1 TRUE. `match()` will return the **first** TRUE element, my first comment will attempt to `unlist()` **all** the TRUE elements.

Comment: `my_list[[match(TRUE, logical_vector)]]` is the best option but I would prefer to output `list()` in the all-FALSE case

Comment: Then I think `if (any(logical_vector)) my_list[[which(logical_vector)]] else list()` is the best option for you.

Comment: The fact that you don't like how cumbersome it is suggests you probably need it wrapped in a function for frequent use: `sub <- function(a, b) if(length(x <- a[b])) x[[1]] else list()` Allows `sub(my_list, logical_vector)`

Comment: `my_list[logical_vector] |> unlist()` doesn't work in my real cas since `my_list` is made of dataframes

Comment: Masking `sub` is bad.

Comment: @jay.sf you're right. `sub` is a terrible name. Naming things is harder than writing the actual code.

Comment: Sounds like yet another reason to use your working one-liner, `if (any(logical_vector)) my_list[[which(logical_vector)]] else list()`

Answer (score -1):

```
my_list <- list(10, "a", 30)
logical_vector <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)

# using ifelse():
ifelse(any(logical_vector), my_list[[which(logical_vector)]], list())  |> unlist()

# or dplyr
dplyr::first(my_list[logical_vector]) |> unlist()
```

This returns:

```
[1] 30
```

For other vector:

```
logical_vector <- c(F, F, F)
ifelse(any(logical_vector), my_list[[which(logical_vector)]], list())  |> unlist()

 # or dplyr
 dplyr::first(my_list[logical_vector]) |> unlist()
```

This returns:

```
NULL
```

But I am still trying to understand what do you mean by **"... but none is straightfoward enough for me"**

Comment: The first solution is too verbose

Comment: The second solution requires a first operation that may be long to compute `my_list[logical_vector]` (if the element is big)